# extra <a> tag is added in wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, tags

I am a wordpress lover and i am facing this issue for the first time, below is the code i am using for making menu to be displayed.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
```

And below is the picture of Google Chrome developer tools to show you the extra  tag in every

[image]

Please help if you have any idea about this, because i am totally clueless at this point.

Comment: You must have some function in your functions.php or a plguin that would have been modifying the nav menu output. Check.

Comment: Thanx for your prompt response Robert. I have searched in functions.php file and found some unwanted functions present there. I have removed all of them, and i have also found this function present twice so i have also removed 1 copy of it. `register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'nav-menu', 'earth-enterprise' ) );` But still no luck with extra `<a>` tag in the menu.